# Google Geocoding API, need name of road/street

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I am using the Google Geocoding API to return results based on a postcode search only.  I get results ok but there is never a road/street component returned.  This generally makes sense as the bounds of a postcode may span over several streets.  How then can I then get a list of streets within those bounds or something similar to achieve an online postcode search?

Comment: please clarify; are you asking how to get a list of road/street names from a postal code? Or are you wanting lat/long for a given postal code?

Comment: also, if you can elaborate a bit more on your overall purpose it might promote good alternatives as well. In other words, please elaborate on "online postcode search".

Comment: Basically an address finder, i.e. putting in postcode and getting back St Marys Road, Grantham, Lincolnshire, NG33 5TG etc (not a real address BTW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the following posts may point you in the right direction: [returning street address google api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310882/google-reverse-geocode-doesnt-always-return-a-street-address) and [get street address by lat/long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158557/get-street-address-at-lat-long-pair).

I assume your goal is to display these on a map. If not, be aware of [Google's TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)  so you don't take a wasted path as others have done (sometimes unknowingly). Specifically: "Note: **the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map**; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited."

This link regarding [address validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134956/how-do-you-perform-address-validation) has some good information as well that may assist you (it gives some details about google and offers some alternatives.

good luck

Comment: Ah I was not aware of that and was not using it for a map so in the interest of being a good citizen I will scrap this idea.  Instead I have looked at PostcodeAnywhere which is testing pretty well.